# Upload form for txt and xlsx in javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I would like to make a form that allow user upload .txt and .xlsx file and write this file's contents in a div.I don't know if i should go server side to handle uploaded files.My server side is written in Java 1.4 and client side is xslt.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://niggler.github.io/js-xlsx/ ?

Comment: i couldn't understand what does your application do?from a weppage user can upload xls or txt file.And my webpage read this file content and response answer to user

Comment: Strictly speaking, if all you want to do is read a .xlsx file and just print the contents, you don't need to go server side.  html5 file api is powerful enough to do it, as demonstrated in my link.